logic app standard local functions with vs code devkit
Has anyone tried building logic app standard with local functions yet and the devkit extension to vs code?
I created a new logic app workspace and followed the steps to select a dotnet 8 local function. You can see the code generated at this github repo.

When I open the folder in vs code, it immediately creates a file named "Function.generated.sln" in the \Function folder. This contains a relative path to the fn1.csproj file that is incorrect, which causes the devkit extension to display an error:


try to refer the steps given https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-run-custom-code-functions doc

Yep, those steps are good and I'm able to create the logic app with the local function ok. My question is more around using with devkit

C# Dev Kit issues are discussed on GitHub https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues
